# TotalRowCount with paging in Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, linq, performance, linq-to-sql, paging

Im getting a paged datasource from a fairly complex linq query. My problem is that is takes twice as long to execute since I need to get the total row count before paging is applied in order to calculate the nr. of pages to dispaly. (the query will be executed twice)

Is there somehow I can do this in a more optimal way? Like using SQL's @@rowcount somehow?

This is roughly what the query looks like right now. (using Dynamic linq)

```
    public IList<User> GetPagedUsers(string filter, string sort, int skip, 
       int take, out int totalRows)
    {
            using(var dbContext = new DataContext())
            {
               IQueryable<User> q = GetVeryComplexQuery(dbContext);

               //Apply filter if exists
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
                   q = q.Where(filter);

               //Set total rows to the out parameter
               totalRows = q.Count(); //Takes 4 sec to run

               //Apply sort if exists
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
                   q = q.OrderBy(sort);

               //Apply paging and return
               return q.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList(); //Takes 4 sec to run
            }
    }
```

Why wont this for example work?

```
TblCompanies.Dump(); //150 rows
ExecuteQuery<int>("select @@ROWCOUNT").Dump(); //returns 0
```

Comment: Is the result set changing on every page? If yes, would the previous page be even valid? If not, then you do not need to get count on every iteration or do a sort.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser I suppose I only need to get the total row count for the initial request or if the filter changes.

Comment: @Magnus : If the filter changes, then your page definition would change. Unless you want to make an abstract method that would return any page, and not just breaking a big result into smaller pages.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Yes, if the filter changes it restarts the paging from the beginning.

Comment: @Magnus, in that case you can break your method into two parts, one that fetches the IQueryable, another that paginates it. That ways you'll not need to count and sort on every request.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser that's a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq2Sql will actually translate the use of Skip & Take into the SQL Statement so even if you could get @@RowCount the value will not be great than your take parameter.

If we take the following simple example (lifted from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx).

```
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery3 =
    (from custs in db.Customers
     where custs.City == "London"
     orderby custs.CustomerID
     select custs)
    .Skip(1).Take(1);

foreach (var custObj in custQuery3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(custObj.CustomerID);
}
```

the following SQL is generated

```
SELECT TOP 1 [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName],
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1 [t1].[CustomerID]
        FROM [Customers] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[City] = @p0
        ORDER BY [t1].[CustomerID]
        ) AS [t2]
    WHERE [t0].[CustomerID] = [t2].[CustomerID]
    ))) AND ([t0].[City] = @p1)
ORDER BY [t0].[CustomerID]
```

So you can see that the skip is actually occurring inside the SQL Statement and therefore @@RowCount is going to equal the amount of rows returned by the query and not the entire result set.

Comment: Your are right about that. I guess the only optimization I can do is to follow  @YetAnotherUser advice and only calc the total count the first time or if the filter changes. But I think Im leaning to retrieve the complete query values (700.000 rows) and keep in the cache. It is actually slightly faster than the 8 sec it takes to do the paging + count. And I dont need to go to the DB for every page.